# Additional step before logging user in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have implemented the default register/login possibility with Laravel 5.4.

Now I wish to add a second factor to authentication. After user enters his credentials I wish to send him an email with a security code and present a user with a form where he inserts the security code from his email. Only after he has inserted the correct security code I wish to allow user to log in.

My question is how is it possible to create this extra step in login flow using Laravel 5.4? Currently the LoginController created by Laravel is empty and I don't know how to get a foothold in the login proccess.

Comment: There are many steps that are required to answer your question. It might be better to break it down into smaller questions such as `Sending confirmation email to user.`, `Verifying user via confirmation URL.` ect. At the minute your question is too broad.

Comment: Actually that was just the description of what i need to do and i know how to do most of that :) The question i asked was how can i get a foothold in the laravels authentication process so i get a possibility to do those steps.

Comment: Use a middleware?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments there are multiple steps to this problem.

1. Generate a secure token.
2. Send an email to the user.
3. Let the user post this token.
4. Check if the user is validated where necessary.

I think the token generation part should be trivial. So to continue:

Send an email to the user, this again can be broken into multiple steps.

1. Detect when a user registered.
2. Broadcast an event.
3. Listen to this event.
4. Handle the event.

   ```
   /**
    * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
    *
    * @param  array  $data
    * @return User
    */
   protected function create(array $data){
       $user = User::create([
           'name' => $data['firstname'] . " " . $data['lastname'],
           'email' => $data['email'],
           'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
           'email_token' => str_random(10),
           'verified' => false
       ]);

       event(new UserRegistered($user));

       return $user;
   }
   ```

For this you will need to add the `email_token` and `verified` fields to your `User` model with migrations.

This wil create a new user and generate a token (this token generation is not secure! After this it will fire an `UserRegistered` event.

This event will look something like:

```
class UserRegistered{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user){
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

To listen to this event you will need to create your listener

```
class UserListener{
    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  UserRegistered  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(UserRegistered $
        Mail::to($event->user)->send(new EmailVerification($event->user));
        //EmailVerficiation is an instance of Mailable;
    }
}
```

And bind this listener to your event, in your `AppServiceProvider` edit the following:

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\UserRegistered' => [
        'App\Listeners\UserListener',
    ],

];
```

After this all you will need to create route with which the users can confirm their email.

You could then create a new middleware:

```
class EmailVerification
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->verified) {

            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('/wait_for_approval'); 
        // Or any other route to indicate that they need to validate their email.
    }
}
```

This middleware will then need to be registered in your `Kernel.php`, in your `$routeMiddleware` add `'auth.approved_email' => \App\Http\Middleware\EmailVerification::class,`

Then you can use this middleware directly or put it in a group with other middleware.

Answer (score -2):

To achieve what you want, you want to use Laravel's middleware. For more information look here - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#registering-middleware

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.** Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Okay only on my phone at the minute so will update when home